# ADODB : Monetary format (number formatting for Euro)

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I display the results of my sql ADODB as :

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_10").Column).Value = RECSET2("Ecart").Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_11").Column).Value = RECSET2("MT_BRUT").Value
```

Do you know, please, how to apply the monetary format ?

Comment: Have you tried `ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_10").Column).NumberFormat = "Currency"`?

Comment: What you may need is cell formatting. `ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_10").Column).NumberFormat  = "$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"`

Comment: @shahkalpesh Thank you, I woud like to have the number like 200,38€, I wrote : ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_11").Column).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00€" ?

Comment: If you office UI language is set right per Europe, it should format the number automatically if I am not wrong. See if [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/439e9a5d-45fb-4d93-a563-6d2a608b7459/how-to-convert-excel-spreadsheet-to-european-style-numbers) helps

Comment: @shahkalpesh yes, I'm in Europe, it's not automatically formated ))

Comment: See if the link I pasted above helps. Office takes the currency and thousand/decimal separator from system and you can override it. I dont know how one can force format it.

Comment: Found it in Excel 2016. On the cell you are, look at the $ button in the ribbon which has a dropdown on it. You should see "More accounting formula". It shows the dialog which has "Symbol" dropdown on the right. Select "€ Euro (123 €) from the dropdown and click OK. Voila. Alternatively, you could do  `NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0.00_) [$€-1]_ ;_ * (#,##0.00) [$€-1]_ ;_ * "-"??_) [$€-1]_ ;_ @_ " `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Found it in Excel 2016.

On the cell you are, look at the $ button in the ribbon which has a dropdown on it.
You should see "More accounting formula". It shows the dialog which has "Symbol" dropdown on the right. Select "€ Euro (123 €) from the dropdown and click OK.

Alternatively, you could do `NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0.00_) [$€-1]_ ;_ * (#,##0.00) [$€-1]_ ;_ * "-"??_) [$€-1]_ ;_ @_ "`